# Ajax code not working to search data

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

i am using normal ajax to search from data base when form submit but the code is not working . There are two date field i want to search data between two dates if i use separate page the code is working but in ajax it is not working .any help will be appreciate Thank you

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<script src="datepicker/javascript/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="datepicker/css/default.css" type="text/css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="datepicker/javascript/zebra_datepicker.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
     $('input.datepicker').Zebra_DatePicker();
    $('#strt_dt').Zebra_DatePicker();
});

$(document).ready(function() {
     $('input.datepicker').Zebra_DatePicker();
    $('#end_dt').Zebra_DatePicker();
});
</script>

<script>
function showStd(tstfrm) {
   if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
    // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
    xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
  } else { // code for IE6, IE5
    xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }
  xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function() {
    if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200) {
    document.getElementById("replace").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
    }
  }

  var strt_dt = document.getElementById('strt_dt').innerHTML;
  var end_dt = document.getElementById('end_dt').innerHTML;
  xmlhttp.open("GET","test2.php?strt_dt="+strt_dt+"&end_dt="+end_dt, true);
  xmlhttp.send();
}

</script>
</head>

<body>
        <form action="" method="post" onsubmit="return showStd(this);" name="tstfrm" id="tstfrm">
              <fieldset>

                 <p><label>Start Date:</label><input name="strt_dt" type="text" class="text-long" id="strt_dt" /></p>
                 <p><label>End Date:</label><input name="end_dt" type="text" class="text-long" id="end_dt" /></p>           

                 <input name="serch" type="submit" id="serch" value="search"/>
              </fieldset>
        </form>
        <div id="replace" style="height:500px; width:1000px; border:1px solid #000;">
                        </div>
</body>
</html>
```

and here is the below test2.php for search

```
<?php
include '../dbconn.php';
$strt_dt=$_REQUEST['strt_dt'];
$end_dt = $_REQUEST['end_dt'];
?>

<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="1">
                            <tr>
                            <td width="137"><b>Name</b></td>
                            <td width="154"><b>Contact</b></td>
                            <td width="407" align="center"><b>Action</b></td>
                            </tr>
                            <?php
                             $qry=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM std_register WHERE reg_dt BETWEEN '".$strt_dt."' AND '".$end_dt."'");

                              while($row=mysql_fetch_array($qry))
                              {
                            ?>
                            <tr>
                                <td><?php echo $row['std_name1']." ".$row['std_name2'];?></td>
                                <td><?php echo $row['std_phno'];?></td>

                            </tr>                        
                              <?php
                              }
                              ?>    
                        </table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Dude i can see in your code that you are using jQuery on the page. 
can use jQuery provided methods for Ajax requests.

1. [$.get](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.get/)
2. [$.post](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/)

And more verbose method [$.ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) for your work you need jQuery to make it cross browser.

```
$.get('/test2.php?date='+date,function(response){
//use server response to manipulate dom
});
```

Comment: i can't because i dont know how to use jquery ajax @ lokeshjain2008 and i use jquery for date picker only

Comment: See the examples on the links that i have listed for your you.